# How to make thymeleaf to ignore the null object?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a spring mvc project project with jsp as view. I need to use thymeleaf now. The old jsp project will auto ignore the manager object, if I don't put the manager object to the ModelMap.

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<c:url value=" /${action} " />">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${manager.id}">
....
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="email" value="${manager.email}" class="form-control1" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">phone</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="mobile" value="${manager.mobile}" class="form-control1" placeholder="phone number">
    </div>
</div>
...
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 ">
        <button class="btn btn-success1 btn-block">sumbit</button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

However Thymeleaf will give a error if I write as

```
     <input type="text" name="email" th:value="${manager.email}" class="form-control1" placeholder="Email">
```

I knew we can check the object as

```
<input type="text" name="mobile" th:value="${manager? manager.mobile : ''}" class="form-control1" placeholder="phone number">
```

Do I have to writte check each of them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a safe navigation & an  elvis operator in Spring EL which you can use in Thymeleaf. Here is the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-elvis)
which describes it. Use it like below in your case which will return null instead of throwing an exception.

```
${manager?.email}
```